# How to add Cocos2d and Box2d to existing Xcode 4.6 project

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

None of the instructions/tutorials I can find on this are working because Xcode changes build settings, etc. with every release. Has anyone done this in Xcode 4.6? I have a project that needs to have some Cocos2d views. I also need Box2d.

Here is what I've done.

-Create a new project based on the Cocos2d with Box2d template. Close this project.

-Navigate to the cocos2d project folder of the new app in Finder. Locate the subfolder named libs in the cocos2d project folder. Drag the libs folder into my current project.

-Add all the necessary libraries

At first it couldn't find kazmath.h. I fixed that. Then it couldn't find a Box2d collision class. Fixed that. Now I get an error in CCActionCamera (ARC forbids autorelease):

```
@implementation CCOrbitCamera
+(id) actionWithDuration:(float)t radius:(float)r deltaRadius:(float) dr angleZ:(float)z deltaAngleZ:(float)dz angleX:(float)x deltaAngleX:(float)dx
{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithDuration:t radius:r deltaRadius:dr angleZ:z deltaAngleZ:dz angleX:x deltaAngleX:dx] autorelease];
}
```

I feel like this is going to be an endless list of errors. I just wish there was a way to simply use Cocos2d in a project.

EDIT #2: After adding the `-fno-objc-arc` flag to all the Cocos2d files:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_ExtAudioFileSetProperty", referenced from:
      _CDloadCafAudioData in CDOpenALSupport.o
  "_ExtAudioFileRead", referenced from:
      _CDloadCafAudioData in CDOpenALSupport.o
  "_AudioFileReadBytes", referenced from:
      _CDloadWaveAudioData in CDOpenALSupport.o
  "_ExtAudioFileDispose", referenced from:
      _CDloadCafAudioData in CDOpenALSupport.o
  "_AudioFileOpenURL", referenced from:
      _CDloadWaveAudioData in CDOpenALSupport.o
  "_AudioFileGetProperty", referenced from:
      _CDloadWaveAudioData in CDOpenALSupport.o
  "_ExtAudioFileGetProperty", referenced from:
      _CDloadCafAudioData in CDOpenALSupport.o
  "_AudioFileClose", referenced from:
      _CDloadWaveAudioData in CDOpenALSupport.o
  "_ExtAudioFileOpenURL", referenced from:
      _CDloadCafAudioData in CDOpenALSupport.o
  "_AudioSessionGetProperty", referenced from:
      -[CDAudioManager isOtherAudioPlaying] in CDAudioManager.o
      -[CDAudioManager isDeviceMuted] in CDAudioManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. Are you saying the cocos2d+Box2D project is broken in Xcode 4.6? Which cocos2d version? If so, tell us what the error is. Xcode doesn't change Build Settings, the compiler is updated and typically catches more potential issues than the previous one. This may be aggravating at times but it is really helpful to know the compiler is getting better at detecting problematic code.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I actually am trying to use your book. I edited my question to show the steps I've done. Any advice?

Comment: for the armv7s issue simply add armv7s as architecture to build settings of all targets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just focus on your current error, **ARC forbids autorelease**. Cocos2d uses manual reference counting, so you have to compile cocos2d without ARC (automatic reference counting):

Go to your project settings, click on your target, go to **Build Phases**, expand **Compile Sources** and select all your cocos2d files (files starting with 'CC'). Press enter, a text box comes up, type in `-fno-objc-arc`. That tells the compiler to not use ARC for those files.
Now hope that this was the last error and hit compile.

Comment: The last error was because I didn't have the AudioToolbox framework, which wasn't mentioned in any of the docs or tutorials I found. It's finally compiling but it's crazy how long this process took.